# How to add numbers in side a complex array using a recurring method in Python?

Tags: python

Given the following list of lists which contain numbers:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,56],[0,1],[[1, 0, 3]]]
```

How would you calculate the total by adding all the numbers in x using a recursive function.

I attempted the following:

```py
def sum_total(array, start_index):
    sum = 0
    if start_index>= len(array):
       return sum

    if type(array[start_index]) is not list:
       sum = sum + array[start_index]
    start_index= start_index+ 1;
    return sum_total(array, start_index)

sum_total(x, 0)
```

- Example 1:

```py
x = [[1,2],[3,56],[0,1],[[1, 0, 3]]]
start_index = 0
result = sum_total(x, start_index)
```

result should be = (1 + 2) + (3 + 56) + (0 + 1) + (1 + 0 + 3)

- Example 2:

```py
    x = [[1,2],[3,56],[0,1],[[1, 0, 3]]]
    start_index = 1
    result = sum_total(x, start_index)
```

result should be = (3 + 56) + (0 + 1) + (1 + 0 + 3)

The method keeps returning `0`. It should return the sum.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Given `x`, what are you trying to arrive at? What have you tried?

Comment: No clue whats being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is defined in terms of a 'trivial case' (plain number) and a 'recursive case' (an array).

What I would do is create a generator that extracts all numbers, and sum over that:

```
def nested_sum(x):
    return sum(numbers(x))
```

Where the `numbers` method is the recursive one

```
def numbers(xs):
  if isinstance(xs, collections.Iterable):
    yield from itertools.chain(*map(numbers, xs))
  else:
    yield xs
```

The `yield from` syntax may look odd - it turns `numbers` into a generator that yields numbers from collections of (collections of...) elements.  It's a very powerful Python feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend writing a generator expression that recursively finds the sum:

```
mySum = lambda x:sum(a if isinstance(a,int) else mySum(a) for a in x)
```